# Difference between postBuild and postprocessTree in Ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Can anyone explain to me the difference between [postBuild](https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Addon.html#method_postBuild) and [postprocessTree](https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Addon.html#method_postprocessTree) using Ember-cli?

The explanation is really vague in the doc and they seem to do the same thing, but I'm sure there is a step between one and other otherwise they wouldn't make two functions.

Comment: One is in the tmp folder where you have symlinks. Between them everything is copied to the dist folder, where the second is executed AFAIK.

Comment: With your information and with their name I'm assuming that the postprocessTree waits you to do something. After that everything is moved to the dist folder then the postBuild is executed. Is that correct?